# There is a still space when I use spread_inside in constraintlayout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I use a land layout with *Layout A*, I have set `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"` for 4 ImageButtons

But I find there is a still space, you can see *Image A*.

BTW, I get the same result when I use `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"`

And more:

If I use a vertical layout with *Layout B,* I found there is no space, you can see *Image B*.

How can I remove space when I use *Layout A* ?

**Layout A**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_on" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnFlash"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"

            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnPicture"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Layout B**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_on" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnFlash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image B**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle` attribute should be set on the first element of the chain. In vertical chains it's the first element from the top, so you should move chain style attribute from `btnFlash` to `btnAction`.

In layout B it works as expected because you have correctly set the attribute on the first chained view on the left.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove your margin top and bottom.

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnVideo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_need_it" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnFlash"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPicture"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like_gray" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnVideo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAction"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_in_love" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnPicture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_got_it" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! but I place the similar code in land layout, it works well.

Comment: And more, the UI are the same when I replace `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"` with `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" `  in your code.